# TLS 1.3 Support

Tags: ssl, windows

I can't find this key in the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Client
“DisabledByDefault”=dword:00000000
“Enabled”=dword:00000001
```

Does anyone know if TLS v1.3 supported on Windows Server 2012 standard?

Comment: TLS 1.3 was officially made a protocol only in Aug 2018. Windows devs are actively working on adding the protocol to into a future release of Windows, but the exact release is TBD. The next release should ship with an *unsupported* preview. It would not be backported to 2012 for the reason @margot4life mentioned.

Comment: Per [Microsoft TLS 1.3 Support Reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/microsoft-tls-1-3-support-reference/) published January 30, 2020: `TLS 1.3 is also supported on Windows 1903 as of release of this article for **testing purposes only, not production environment**.`

Comment: What is driving this requirement? From a security perspective, TLS1.2 is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 does not support TLS 1.3. [Source](https://support.globalsign.com/ssl/general-ssl/tls-protocol-compatibility)

Besides, it is in the "Extended Support" status, so there won't be any new features but only security updates.